# Remote procedure call in linux

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming, rpc

This is my client code

cl.c

```
#include "S.h"
 int main()
 {
   CLIENT *cl;
   cl=clnt_create("127.0.0.1",S_PROG,S_VERS,"tcp");
   struct st i,*o;i.a=3;
   o=square_1(&i,cl);
   printf("%d",o->a);
   return 0;
  }
```

Server code

server1.c

```
#include "S.h"
 struct st* square_1_svc(struct st *i,struct svc_req *r)
 {
   static struct st o;
   o.a=i->a*i->a;
   return &o;
 }
```

S.x

```
struct st
{
  int a;
};
program S_PROG
{
   version S_VERS
   {
       st square(st)=1;
   }=1;
}=OX31231234;
```

compilation procedure

```
rpcgen -C S.x
gcc -c S_xdr.c
gcc -c S_clnt.c
gcc -c S_svc.c
gcc -c cl.c
gcc -c server1.c
```

building object file manually

```
gcc -o rpccl S_xdr.o S_clnt.o cl.o -lnsl
gcc -o rpcserver1 S_xdr.o S_svc.o server1.o -lnsl

./rpserver1
./spccl
```

when i run my client output file i.e in "./spccl" line i am getting segmentation fault .

Comment: Use `gcc -Wall -g` as your compiler (e.g. compile `cl.c` with `gcc -Wall -g -c cl.c` etc....), and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger. Check that `cl` is not `NULL`; perhaps use also `strace` on both client and server.